# Powershell script gets error saying remote registry service is not turned on when it is

Tags: powershell, service, registry, event-viewer

I have a powershell script that searches the miner logs in the applications and services folder in the event viewer and returns all logs classified as error for the ArcMap application. The script searches for every machine in our company's network. The script works when it searches on a single machine, however it returns an error saying it cannot find the RemoteRegistry service when the script searches on multiple machines. Below is the script I have so far.

```
$computers = Get-Content "computerlist.txt"
$logFile = "MinerErrorLogs.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $computers -Name "RemoteRegistry" | Set-Service -StartupType Manual        -PassThru| Start-Service 
    Write-Host "Processing computer $computer..."
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application'; ProviderName='ArcMap'; Level=2}
    $events | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\$logFile" -Append
}

Get-Service -ComputerName $computers -Name "RemoteRegistry" | Set-Service -Status Stopped
```

I have made sure the Get-Service command is included in the loop and that it stops the service when finished. Not sure why it says it cannot find it when the script tell the service to start.

Tried the "Get-Service command, put it in the loop so it turns on for every machine searched. Expected the "cannot find service" error to disappear, but it is still there.

Comment: The error may be occurring on some machines and not all machines.  Add an exception handler that will display the machine name that fails.

Comment: We can, but unfortunately, that will not be helpful.

We already know that the service in on manual and not running, and the command is not going through so its initial manual state still stands. All machines have the service.

Comment: You need to run Start-Service (not Get-Service) to start the service before getting results.

Comment: I have the Start-Service command at the end of that line. Are you saying I need to remove Get-Service entirely?

Comment: Don't you want to start the service before getting the results?

Comment: No because that service needs to stay off when the script isn't running. It's a security risk when it is on.

Comment: I have read your code five times now. I see “get-service”, I see “set-service”. What I can not find is the expression “start-service”. But wait let me read a sixth time… nope no “start-service”. Can u give us the complete code pls?

Comment: You cannot run a script that is not already running.  So you need to 1) Start 2) Run 3) Stop

Comment: Why are you looping through the array of computers an then inside that loop you call Get-Service on the entire array `$computers` instead of the single `$computer` you are iterating with ??

Comment: @Dom start-service is at the end of the 5th line, the one that begins with Get-Service. @jdweng the service needs to stay off. It only starts when the script starts. @Theo `$computers` is the array that is being iterated and that is what I want to do, not sure what you mean by the single `$computer`.

Comment: Very simple... You iterate through the **array** named `$computers` using a variable `$computer` (singular), but then when it comes to calling `Get-Service` you again feed it the entire array, where that should be the single iterating variable `$computer` (no **s**)

Comment: Ah ok got it. Tried running it again and still got the same error message.

Comment: I tested and in my case the RemoteRegistry service is stopped, witch is not stoping me from querying the machine with Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application'; ProviderName='ArcMap'; Level=2}. Of course the Provider "ArcMap" does not exist in my case, but the question stands: What is RemoteRegistry needed for in this case? Is there something else happening witch I can not see here or is this line totally obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Second approach would be to use pssession to run the code from the inside:

```
foreach ($client in $file){
   $Session=New-PSSession -ComputerName $client -errorAction SilentlyContinue
   if($Session){
      Write-Host "Processing computer $computer..."
      $rslt=Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
        #$remoteRegService = Get-Service -Name "RemoteRegistry"                   
        #$remoteRegService | Set-Service -StartupType Manual  -PassThru | Start-Service 
        Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application'; ProviderName='ArcMap'; Level=2} $events | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\$logFile" -Append                                               
        #$remoteRegService | Set-Service -Status Stopped                         
      } 
     $rslt | Out-File -FilePath "$env:TEMP\$logFile" -Append                                                                        
     Remove-pssession $Session
   }                                                                            
}
```

I have left the command on RemoteRegistry in the code block but commented them out, since it is possible to use them to start / stop the service but in this case from within the client there is no obvious reason to use the service.